# If Banach space is dense in anothe Bamach space, will the dual space dense as well?

Tags: real-analysis, duality-theorems

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. $X\subset Y$ is dense in $Y$. Prove or disprove: 
$Y^*$ is dense in $X^*$.

I tried as follows. Since $X\subset Y$, then $Y^*\subset X^*$. Let $f\in X^*\setminus Y^*$. I tried to construct a sequence $f_n\in Y^*$, $f_n\to f$, but failed.

Comment: Why $Y^*\subset X^*$ ?

Comment: Look for a counterexample in a well-known family of spaces.

Comment: To Tsemo Aristide.
If $X\subset Y$ then $\forall f\in Y^*$, functional $f$ is defined on $X$. Then $f\in X^*$. Consequently, 
$Y^*\subset X^*$.

Comment: To Daniel Fischer:
I consider spaces $L^p(0,1)$. We know $L^2\subset L^1$ and $L^2$ is dense in $L^1$. But $(L^1)^*\subset (L^2)^*$ because $L^\infty \subset L^2$ and $L^\infty$ is dense in $L^2$. So, this counterexample doesn't work. Maybe you mean another counter example?